# How to find the differential of this function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

we are given the function $f: \mathbb R^n \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb R^n$ defined by:

$f(x) = \frac{x}{|x|}$

Find $Df(a)$.

What I did:

I tried working this out from the definition. the differential at point $a$ with direction $h$ is:

$$Df(a)h= \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(a+th)-f(a)}{t} =\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\frac{a+th}{|a+th|}-\frac{a}{|a|}}{t} =\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{a}{t|a+th|}-\frac{a}{t|a|}+\frac{h}{|a+th|} $$

How do I continue now?

The correct answer is $$Df(a)h=\frac{h}{|a|}-\frac{a \langle a,h \rangle}{|a|^3}$$

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want the [differential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix) or the directional derivative in any direction?

Comment: directional derivative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working directly with the definitions might work, but looks tedious to me. You should first calculate the differential of the functions involved, then use the quotient rule:
$$f_1(x)= x: \quad df_1(x)v = v$$
(I leave the verification of this to you..)
Now let
$$f_2(x):=|x|^2 = \langle x, x \rangle $$ This is the evaluation of the bilinear scalar product on $x$. So
$$df_2(x) v = \langle x, v \rangle+\langle v, x \rangle= 2 \langle x, v \rangle$$
(again, I leave the verification of this to you..). From this we see (using the chain or product rule) that for $f_3(x) = |x|$ 
$$df_2(x)v = 2|x|d f_3(x)v = 2\langle x, v\rangle$$
 From this you can solve for the differential of $|x|$. Now you only have to put the pieces together.