# Find the gradient of $f:\Bbb R^m\setminus\{0\}\to\Bbb R,\; x\mapsto |x|$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, frechet-derivative

> Find the gradient of $f:\Bbb R^m\setminus\{0\}\to\Bbb R,\; x\mapsto |x|$.

Can someone check if the reasoning below is correct? Thank you in advance.

Note: here it is assumed that $|x|=\|x\|_2$. Using directional derivatives I found that (with a slight abuse of notation on vectors)

$$D_vf(x)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x+tv)-f(x)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac1t\left(\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^m (x_k+tv_k)^2}-\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^mx_k^2}\right)\\=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^m(x_k+tv_k)v_k}{|x+tv|}=\langle x/|x|,v\rangle$$

where I used L'Hôpital rule in the second step. Thus if the differential of $f$ would exists then $\partial f(x)v=D_vf(x)=\langle x/|x|,v\rangle$, and because the proposed $\partial f(x)$ is a linear function we can conclude that indeed it is the differential of $f$, thus the gradient at any point $x\in\Bbb R^m\setminus\{0\}$ is $x/|x|$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the differential of this function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816227/how-to-find-the-differential-of-this-function)

Comment: @Anne this was to check the **reasoning, not the result**, so NO, the linked question doesn't answer if my reasoning is correct or not.

Comment: Ok, I retracted my close vote. I note however that the accepted answer also focuses on the result, not on your reasoning. Btw, your argument about linearity was useless. If the differential exists then necessarily $\partial f(x)v=D_vf(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. This works. Another way to see it is to observe that 
$$\langle x, x\rangle=\vert x \vert^2\;,$$
where $\langle , \rangle$ is the standard inner product. The gradient operator satisfies the Leibniz rule
$$\nabla \langle x, x\rangle=\langle dx,x\rangle+\langle x,dx\rangle=2\langle dx,x\rangle=2x\;.$$
Here $d$ denotes the differential (i.e. jacobian matrix) of a vector valued function and the notation indicates that we're considering $\langle dx,x\rangle$ as a vector quantity whose $i$-th component is the inner product with the $i$-th column of the differential. On the other hand, we also have the chain rule from which
$$\nabla\langle x, x\rangle=2\vert x \vert \cdot \nabla \vert x \vert\;,$$
provided $\vert x \vert$ is differentiable (which it is on $\mathbb{R}^m-\{0\}$). Combining, 
$$\nabla \vert x \vert=x/\vert x \vert\;.$$