# Finding the derivative of $f(x)=x/||x||$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to find the derivative of the function $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ given by $f(x)=x/||x||$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{0\}$ and $f(0)=0$.

I've actually already been given the following expression $$f'(x)(h)=\frac{h}{||x||} - \frac{\langle x,h \rangle x}{||x||^3}$$ but cannot find a nice way to prove that this is in fact the derivative of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{0\}$.

---

What I've tried is to use the definition $$f(x+h)=f(x) + T(h) + ||h|| \varepsilon(h)$$ where $T(h)$ is a linear map that ends up being the derivative if it exists, and $\varepsilon(0)=0$ and is continuous at $0$. Plugging the function and the given derivative in, it seems you have to show that for $x,h \in \mathbb{R}^3$, $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{||h||} \left(\frac{x+h}{||x+h||} - \frac{(x+h)}{||x||} + \frac{\langle x,h \rangle x}{||x||^3} \right)=0$$ and I can't see a nice way of showing this. I don't know if doing this is the intended way or if there is a much easier way. I've tried looking at the components of $f$ since $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if and only if its component functions are also differentiable at $a$, but those expressions aren't any nicer than the one above.

How do you show that the given function is the derivative of $f$?

Comment: Look for the  directional derivative  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative

Comment: Find the derivative of the norm, then apply the quotient rule..

Comment: Is there a reason not to write, in Cartesian coordinates,$$f(x, y, z) = \frac{(x, y, z)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$$and calculate partials?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3726935/why-is-x-fracxx/3726948#3726948

Comment: its better to use \| instead of || to note a norm

Comment: I suggest you to learn the rules of derivative and how to evaluate it. It's pretty common to apply those rules and evaluate derivatives at some points. For example,  imagine that you want to derivate a function that is a product of a matrix with a vector, how would you calculate the jacobian of it? This problem is pretty common. Practice it a lot! It is worth the time. I'm seeing that you are practicing. So keep with it. Learing a bit of matrix calculus is cool as well. With time, you will recognize immediately. For example, jacobian is:$$ J_{f}(x) = \dfrac{I}{\|x\|}-\dfrac{x x^{T}}{\|x\|^3}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\|x+h\|-\|x\|=\sqrt{x^2+2\langle h,x\rangle+h^2}-x^2=\frac{2\langle h,x\rangle+h^2}{\sqrt{x^2+2\langle h,x\rangle+h^2}+x^2}\sim\frac{\langle h,x\rangle}{\|x\|}$$

and from this the "derivative" of $x\dfrac1{\|x\|}$:

$$h\frac1{\|x\|}-x\frac{\dfrac{\langle h,x\rangle}{\|x\|}}{\|x\|^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

This kind of computations is best handled using differentials.

It holds
$$
df = 
\frac{\|\mathbf{x}\| d\mathbf{x}-(d\|\mathbf{x}\|) \mathbf{x}}{\|\mathbf{x}\|^2}
$$
The differential of the norm is
$
\frac{1}{\|\mathbf{x}\|} \mathbf{x}^T d\mathbf{x}
$
yielding
$$
df(\mathbf{x})[d\mathbf{x}]= 
\frac{1}{\|\mathbf{x}\|} d\mathbf{x} -
\frac{1}{\|\mathbf{x}\|^3} \mathbf{x} \mathbf{x}^T d\mathbf{x}
$$
This is the desired expression when replacing $d\mathbf{x}$ by $\mathbf{h}$.

Comment: I think OP wants to prove the derivative using some definition, not to find the derivative.

Comment: maybe, however the title of the question is  "Finding the derivative [] "

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps to introduce a "velocity" term. Here $d\vec{x}/dt$ plays the role of $h$ above.

$\vec{f}=\vec{x}/\sqrt{\vec{x}\cdot\vec{x}}=\nabla r.$

$\frac{d\vec{f}}{dt}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\vec{x}\cdot\vec{x}}}\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}-\vec{x}(\frac{1}{2})(2\vec{x}\cdot\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt})(\vec{x}\cdot{\vec{x}})^{-3/2}$

$\frac{d\vec{f}}{dt}=\frac{\vec{x}\cdot\vec{x}}{(\vec{x}\cdot\vec{x})^{3/2}}\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}-\frac{\vec{x}\cdot\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}}{(\vec{x}\cdot\vec{x})^{3/2}}\vec{x}=\vec{x}\times(\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}\times \vec{x})/(\vec{x}\cdot\vec{x})^{3/2}$

So $\frac{d\vec{f}}{dt}=\vec{f}\times (\frac{1}{(\vec{x}\cdot\vec{x})^{1/2}}\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}\times \vec{f})$

So the vector change of $\vec{f}$ changes in a direction perpendicular to itself and the change $d\vec{x}$.

Take the dot product with both sides we find that $\vec{f} \cdot d\vec{f}/dt=0$ everywhere, telling us the modulus of $\vec{f}$ is constant. Of course this can be found by dotting it with itself $\vec{f}\cdot\vec{f}=1$.