# Differential of the function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} $

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

- I have the following simple question find the differential: $D\phi(x;y) (h_1 ; h_2) $ of the function: $ \phi(x;y):= \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\begin{pmatrix}
  x  \\ 
  y  
  \end{pmatrix},$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0;0)\}$.
- The answer is $$D\phi(x;y)(h_1 ; h_2) = \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}  \begin{pmatrix}
  h_1 \\ 
  h_2 
  \end{pmatrix} - \frac2{(x^2+y^2)^2}\begin{pmatrix}
  x\\ 
  y
  \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
  h_1\\ 
  h_2
  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
  x\\ 
  y
  \end{pmatrix}^T$$
  but I don't undersand why? More precisely: why isn't $ D\phi(x;y)(h_1 ; h_2)$ equal to $ J \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
  h_1\\ 
  h_2
  \end{pmatrix} $ with $J$  the Jacobian matrix?
- I know that this is a very simple question of understanding but I am stuck as I do not see on which formula of the differential this result stands.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The answer is completely wrong. At the very least, some large parentheses are needed, and the answer should be the result of applying a linear map to the vector $h$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the gradient of $f:\Bbb R^m\setminus\{0\}\to\Bbb R,\; x\mapsto |x|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2415111)

Comment: @TedShifrin thank a lot for your answer. As I am learning alone i was stuck hours on this question

Comment: @AnneBauval not exactly but yet it helps me a lot to understand. Thk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your thinking is correct. They seem to have made numerous errors. We have a map $\Bbb R^2-\{0\}\to\Bbb R^2$, so the derivative at the point $(x,y)$ should be a linear map from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^2$. Indeed, since the function is continuously differentiable, this linear map is given by the matrix of partial derivatives. So we should have
$$D\phi(x,y)\begin{pmatrix}h_1\\h_2\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} \frac{y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} & -\frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} \\ -\frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} & \frac{x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}h_1\\h_2\end{pmatrix}.$$
We can certainly rewrite this in the form
$$\frac1{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\begin{pmatrix}y\\-x\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}y\\-x\end{pmatrix}^\top \begin{pmatrix} h_1\\h_2\end{pmatrix}.$$ But their answer is nothing but mistakes.

Comment: Thank a lot for your time and answer i was stuck on it for a long time!

Comment: Very frustrating that it has so many errors in one answer. By the way, I do not know what precisely you are working on learning, but you might check out some of my YouTube videos on multivariable mathematics, linked in my profile. They might be helpful to you.

Comment: I am going to send an email to the person to ask for clarification. Generally there is no such big errors. 
The rest of the course deal with "variety" and I think that's why we are insisting on the part of what is the "differentiable $D \left \{f(x;y)  \right \} (h_1; h_2) $